# missing ibmUtilitiesDomain ent and mod file in DITA-OT

Tags: dita, dita-ot

I have the following code segment

```
  <!ENTITY % ibmut-d-dec     PUBLIC
    "-//IBM//ENTITIES DITA IBM Utilities Domain//EN"
    "../../utilities/ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent">
    %ibmut-d-dec;




   <!ENTITY % ibmut-d-def     PUBLIC
"-//IBM//ELEMENTS DITA IBM Utilities Domain//EN"
"../../utilities/ibmUtilitiesDomain.mod">
%ibmut-d-def;
```

in dtd file, but i am missing these files.

Can anyone suggest how to get **ibmUtilitiesDomain.ent** and **ibmUtilitiesDomain.mod** files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why these are in the DTD declaration. They should be unique to IBM. As long as you have the utilities domain declared, I'm fairly sure you can just remove those declarations as long as the content you're building is not IBM source. If you do receive IBM content, it should pass through to the OT defaults.